# Joda ISODateTimeFormat not using timezone in String

Tags: java, jodatime, freemarker, iso8601

I have a two part issue, or maybe its two different ways to solve this. I receive an ISO string like 2015-11-17T17:10:24-0800. The end goal is to display the string as 11/17/15 5:10 PM in some HTML generated by some Freemarker. The string I receive could be in any timezone, but I always need to display the string in its local timezone as shown above. Currently, our code was just taking the string and passing it into the template and coverting as such:

```
<#assign mydate = obj.mydate?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")?string.short>
```

This is no longer good since I believe Freemarker is using the system's local timezone and now we are getting more than one timezone. I see there is an iso method in freemarker. So I try

```
<#assign order_date = order.order_date?iso("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")>
```

but I keep getting error:

```
For "?iso" left-hand operand: Expected a date, but this evaluated to a string
```

Ok I need a date. Working with Joda, I try and create a datetime object by:

```
DateTime dateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime("2015-11-17T17:10:24-0800");
```

But that appears to use my local timezone as well and shows 2015-11-17T20:10:24.000-05:00. I know I could do withZone(...) but I dont know the zone other than the -0800 or whatever zone is passed at the end of the string. So I'm at a loss of what to do now. Oh, and I cannot change the format of the string I receive.

Comment: FreeMarker displays `java.util.Date`-s with the time zone specified via its `time_zone` setting. The local time zone of the server is only the default. Furthermore when parsing dates that contains a time zone, the current time zone doesn't mater. `?iso`, as the documentation clearly states, is for formatting dates, not for parsing them. `?datetime` is for parsing dates, and it can also parse ISO dates (see documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarification. I did end up using the time_zone setting. I had a hard time understanding the different purpose of iso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime dateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime("2015-11-17T17:10:24-0800");
```

This will create a `DateTime` with a fixed timezone offset of `-08:00`.

Comment: My hero! Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

May require a little more work, but you could always use the [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to create your own custom display for the Date Time. This way you could drop the TimeZone if you care to and render it for within that TimeZone or render locally.

Comment: Limited to Java 7 at the moment I'm afraid. Also trying to use manual solutions such as that as a last resort. Honestly, I'm prepared to just parse the string and never even go to a date object.